# Get the list of repositories of users from GitHub

Tags: node.js, express, github

Im trying to achieve the following things in application created from scratch using nodeJs.

1. Read the list of users from a file in my solution.
2. Get all the public repositories of those users.

**Below is my code**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const request = require('request');
const fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var rootDir = process.argv.length > 2 ? process.argv[2] : process.cwd();
var filePath = path.join(rootDir, "userList.txt");
const https = require('https');



app.listen(3002, function () {
    console.log("Server running on port 3002...");
});

app.get("/getUserRepository", function (req, res, next) {
       fs.readFile("myFilePath/myFile.txt", {encoding: "UTF8"}, function (err, userListObject) {
         getDataObject(userListObject);
     });
});

function getDataObject(userList) {
    var userRepoData = [];
    var userListArray = userList.split(",");
    userListArray.forEach(function (userListObject) {
        https.request("https://api.github.com/users/" + userListObject + "/repos", function (res) {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function (data) {
                userRepoData.push(JSON.parse(data));

            });
        }).end();
    });
}
```

The challenge im facing is, when im making a separate call to get the repo of each user, im getting exception

**"Request forbidden by administrative rules. Please make sure your request has a User-Agent header (http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required)."**

Im not finding any example / approach as to where i can add the user-agent.

Also one more thing that i want to know is, where this is the best approach to achieve what i want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
userListArray.forEach(function (userListObject) {
var options = {
  url: "https://api.github.com/users/" + userListObject + "/repos",
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'my node app'
  }
};
    https.request(options, function (res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (data) {
            userRepoData.push(JSON.parse(data));

        });
    }).end();
});
```

Comment: still not able to connect, getting th error : 
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)

Comment: That is strange error. You can use node playground to put relevant code there and share link with us here so that we can help you. Maybe broader view of the code could reveal the cause of the problem https://www.katacoda.com/courses/nodejs/playground

Answer (score 0):

As the error says you are missing a header `User-Agent`. Refactor your code like this

```
function getDataObject(userList) {
let userRepoData = [];

let userListArray = userList.split(",");

let options = {
    host: 'api.github.com',
    path: '/users/' + username + '/repos',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'user-agent': 'node.js'}
};

userListArray.forEach(function (userListObject) {
    https.request(options, function (res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (data) {
            userRepoData.push(JSON.parse(data));

        });
     }).end();
  });
}
```

You can read more about [User-Agent here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent).

Basically you need to pass how are you trying to access `github api`. If you try with browser it automatically sends the `user-agent`, similar with `postman` but once writing a script you need to manually pass the `user-agent`